# Apache OFBiz controller.xml "You are not allowed to view this page"

Tags: xml, controller, ofbiz

I had figured out how to embed ftl with css and bootstrap to the **screen** (Screens.xml). Unfortunately, I am encountering problems with the **controller.xml** file of the component that I created. Whenever I try to run ant load-demo start after finishing up the controller.xml, it prompts **"You are not allowed to view this page."**

I haven't seen good solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your question as I don't have enough reputation points :D. Your problem seems like a component permission issue. Check if your new component has this in your ofbiz-component.xml:

```
<webapp name="yourComponentName"
       title="yourComponentTitle"
       server="default-server"
       base-permission="OFBTOOLS"
       location="webapp/yourComponent"
       mount-point="/yourComponent"
       app-bar-display="false"/>
```

Thing to notice here is the **base-permission**. If you are logged in as an admin(who has by default OFBTOOLS as there base permission) you'll not be facing any issue.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the comment. I checked ofbiz-component.xml and I found
<pre> <code>
<webapp name="irmabrown"
        title="IrmAbrown"
        server="default-server"
        location="webapp/irmabrown"
        base-permission="OFBTOOLS, IRMABROWN"
        mount-point="/irmabrown"
        app-bar display="false"/>
But still, it does not allow me to view the page. I have to delete what I have added to controller.xml in order to view it.

Comment: can you post what you have written in your controller.xml?

Comment: <!-- Request Mappings -->
    <request-map uri="main"><security https="true" auth="true"/><response name="success" type="view" value="main"/></request-map>
    <request-map uri="login"><security https="true" auth="true"/><response name="success" type="view" value="login"/></request-map>

<!-- View Mappings -->
    <view-map name="main" type="screen" page="component://irmabrown/widget/IrmAbrownScreens.xml#main"/>
    <view-map name="login" type="screen" page="component://irmabrown/widget/IrmAbrownScreens.xml#login"/>

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed a similar problem: search for

```
    <if-has-permission permission="WHATEVER" action="_VIEW"/>
```

I found it in CommonScreens then added a permission manually (WHATEVER_VIEW) to the new security group that I had created for the new user login that I had created.

(https://localhost:8443/webtools/control/addSecurityPermissionToSecurityGroup)

This controls security at the level of the particular screen.